# Is there a way to view/edit an object's x, y coordinates in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Sometimes I'd like to see or edit an object's x, y coordinates.

Is there a way to do this in PowerPoint?

Sample use cases:

- Aligning multiple motion paths
- Verifying object alignment
- Distributing objects along unequal patterns of space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the object and click Size and Position, and on the control panel extend the Position section to see relative position from different anchor points on the stage.

[powerpoint object position screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJCe9.png)